# Set background color with text from url?

Tags: android, url, text, background

So i have an activity that imports a list of names from a .txt that is on a webserver.
But how do i set the background color? On the page that shows the names in the app?
Because it doesnt use the layout i set? Which is roster.xml
Do i have to do something to the .txt file?

Roster.class code:

```
package com.frede.iii;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IIIRoster extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.roster);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);




//      Scrollview
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

    /* We will show the data we read in a TextView. */ 
    TextView tv = new TextView(this); 

    /* Will be filled and displayed later. */ 
    String myString = null; 
    try { 
         /* Define the URL we want to load data from. */ 
        //http://androidtest.host.org/roster.txt
         URL myURL = new URL( 
                   "http://androidtest.host.org/roster.txt"); 
         /* Open a connection to that URL. */ 
         URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection(); 

         /* Define InputStreams to read 
          * from the URLConnection. */ 
         InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream(); 
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 

         /* Read bytes to the Buffer until 
          * there is nothing more to read(-1). */ 
         ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50); 
         int current = 0; 
         while((current = bis.read()) != -1){ 
              baf.append((byte)current); 
         } 

         /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */ 
         myString = new String(baf.toByteArray()); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
         /* On any Error we want to display it. */ 
         myString = e.getMessage(); 
    } 
    /* Show the String on the GUI. */ 
    tv.setText(myString); 
//        Adds  textview to scrollview   
        sv.addView(tv);

//          Sets contentview to scrollview    
        this.setContentView(sv); 
    }
}
```

Comment: do you only want to set text color..? or background color for whole view..?

Comment: Background color for the whole view!

Comment: Okay thanks :) Leave an answer and i will accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you can simple use `tv.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.XYX)` or `sv.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.XYX)`

Also at the same time a textColor can be applied to text as `tv.setTextColor(COLOR.XYX)`

For defining you own colors to be used at run time, use the following:

1.In the string.xml file use the following tag

```
<color name="mycolor">#F5DC49</color>
```

Now in your code.

```
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor))
```

2.Also we can set RGB values as:

```
tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(170, 00, 00));
```

Comment: You can also use Color.parseColor("#F5DC49")

Comment: Thank u Sky Kelsey for more details.